# Erro ao compilar Projeto MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com C# no monodevelop, estava tudo indo muito bem, até quando eu tendo estender a classe Form e recebo o seguinte erro:

> /Volumes/Recover/Developer/WebCamTestA/WebCamTestA/VideoControl.cs(44,44):
>   Error CS0012: The type System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a
>   reference to assembly System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' (CS0012) (WebCamTestA)

Já importei todas as dependências necessárias para trabalhar com Windows.Form, mas ainda continuo com o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente precisa referenciar a dll `System.dll` ao projeto onde estar acontecendo esse erro.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Era isso mesmo que eu precisava.